# How to store the result of function to datafram with related column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

Return Data from function as dictionary and store it in data frame.
While run it using for loop getting error.

```
import pyowm
from pyowm.utils import config
from pyowm.utils import timestamps
owm = pyowm.OWM(" your free api key from OpenWeatherMap")
mgr = owm.weather_manager()

data =[]
# Create function to get weather details
def get_weather(city):
    observation = mgr.weather_at_place(city)
    l = observation.weather
    Wind_Speed = l.wind()['speed']
    Temp = l.temperature('celsius')['temp']
    Max_temp = l.temperature('celsius')['temp_max']
    Min_temp = l.temperature('celsius')['temp_min']
    #Heat_index = l.heat_index
    Humidity = l.humidity
    Pressure = l.pressure['press']
    weather = {"City": city, "Wind_Speed" : Wind_Speed, "Temp": 
                    Temp,"Max_temp":Max_temp, "Min_temp":Min_temp, 
                    "Humidity":Humidity, "Pressure":Pressure}
    return weather


for city in df_location['City']:
    get_weather(city)
    df = df.append(data, True)
```

Want to store that weather details in same df with relative city.

Current df_location is like:
[image]

Comment: Where you have written `Wind_Speed,Temp,Max_temp,Min_temp,Humidity,Pressure = get_weather(c)`, what do you think that line of code does? Where you have written `tmp['Wind_Speed'] = weather['Wind_Speed']`, where do you expect the value of `weather` to come from?

Comment: If the question is really "how do I create a DataFrame that holds the data from a dict?", then you should actually ask that question. But before asking it *here*, you should search for duplicates, and even before that, try looking at the documentation.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Thanks for the replay, sorry my bad, Yes the question is how can I store the result of function to datafram with related city. I updated the question please check.

Comment: So what happened when you tried putting `create dataframe from dictionary` [into a search engine](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=create+dataframe+from+dictionary)?

Comment: I tried a lot but not getting data in DF.

Comment: Not necessarily to use the function, is there any way like using ```for``` loop I can store the data in df.